# Python and creating 2d numpy arrays from list

Tags: python, numpy

I'm running into some trouble converting values in columns into a Numpy 2d array. What I have as an output from my code is something the following:

```
38617.0 0 0
40728.0 0 1
40538.0 0 2
40500.5 0 3
40214.0 0 4
40545.0 0 5
40352.5 0 6
40222.5 0 7
40008.0 0 8
40017.0 0 9
40126.0 0 10
40029.0 0 11
39681.5 0 12
39973.0 0 13
39903.0 0 14
39766.5 0 15
39784.0 0 16
39528.5 0 17
39513.5 0 18
```

And this continues for ~300,000 lines. The coords of the data are arranged as (z,x,y), and I want to convert it into a 2d array with dimensions 765X510 (x,y) so that the z-coordinates are sitting at their respective (x,y) coordinates so that I may write it to an image file.

Any ideas? I've been looking around and I haven't found anything on the matter.

---

EDIT:

This is the while-loop that's creating the above columns of data (it's actually two, a function is called within another while-loop):

```
def make_median_image(x,y):
        while y < 509:
                y = y + 1 # Makes the first value (x,0), b/c Python is indexed at 0
                median_first_row0 = sc.median([a11[y,x],a22[y,x],a33[y,x],a44[y,x],a55[y,x],a66[y,x],a77[y,x],a88[y,x],a99[y,x],a1010[y,x]])
                print median_first_row0,x,y
                list1 = [median_first_row0,x,y]
                list = list1.append(

while x < 764:
        x = x + 1
        make_median_image(x,y)
```

Comment: so you have a text file or a list?

Comment: I have a text file right now, but I would like to take the output from the while-loop and create a list with these values in the code instead of having to read it from a text file. In other words, I don't want to have to create a text file every time I run it, I just want to save the list to a variable etc.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Would it be possible to append and add the (z,x,y) to the end of an empty list (to start with) every time the while-loop cycles through?

Comment: The dimensions of the images are 765 X 510. The function takes the image arrays a11,a22,a33 etc. and gets the median for every individual pixel. For example, it will look at the pixels at (0,0) in all 10 images, read the associated pixel values, and then find the median of all of the pixels at (0,0), then do the same for the rest of the pixels. The goal of this code is to create a "median image", pixel-by-pixel, by not comparing the median of all of the images and then picking the image nearest to median, but to build an image from the median values of all of the pixels.

Comment: what do you mean by add?

Comment: Your intention is unclear about how to pass `y` between the main script and `make_median_image`.  Did you mean for it to be a global variable or a parameter?  My guess is that you don't really want `y` to be a parameter of `make_median_image` but rather a global variable that advances between calls of `make_median_image`.

Comment: Since you seem to know how many rows you're adding to the list on each round, why not allocate an array and fill it with vectors?  Then, `make_median_image` would return an `ndarray` and you could  append them together in the while loop to make a nice convenient (and space-efficient) big ndarray.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out...thanks guys :) I'll post solution in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
l = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [0,0,0]]
```

You can directly pass a python 2D list into a numpy array.

```
>>> np.array(l)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

If you only want the latter two columns (which are your x,y values)

```
>>> np.array([[i[1],i[2]] for i in l])
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 6],
       [8, 9],
       [0, 0]])
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying here, and I'll utilize this when I've created the list you have above, i.e. l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[0,0,0]], but first I need to make this list from the output of the while-loop. How might I go about constructing this?

Comment: I don't know without seeing your while loop :) Can you edit your code to include how that loop is outputting the data you showed in your original post?

Comment: @Cyber if you want the two columns you can also do `a[:, 1:]` where `a` is the numpy array you created from the list...

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to create an array from the data below like so?

Data:

```
38617.0 0 0
40728.0 0 1
40538.0 0 2
40500.5 0 3
40214.0 0 4
40545.0 0 5
40352.5 0 6
40222.5 0 7
40008.0 0 8
40017.0 0 9
40126.0 0 10
40029.0 0 11
39681.5 0 12
39973.0 0 13
39903.0 0 14
39766.5 0 15
39784.0 0 16
39528.5 0 17
39513.5 0 18
... (continues for ~100,000 lines, so you can guess why I'm adamant to find an answer)
```

What I would like:

```
numpy_ndarray = [[38617.0, 40728.0, 40538.0, 40500.5, 40214.0, 40545.0, 40352.5, ... (continues until the last column value in the data above is 764) ], [begin next line, when x = 1, ... (until last y-value is 764)], ... [ ... (some last pixel value)]]
```

So it basically builds a matrix/image grid out of the pixel values in the first column of data that's associated with the (x,y) coordinate in the second and third columns.

Answer (score 0):

lets say your array is l

```
import numpy as np
l = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [0,0,0]]

>>> np.array(l)
array([[1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9],
   [0, 0, 0]])
```

this should work

```
>>> np.array([[i[1] for i in l],[i[2] for i in l]])
array([[2, 5, 8, 0],
   [3, 6, 9, 0]])
```